# React-table multi select filter not filtering data

Tags: reactjs, filter, functional-programming, react-select, react-table

I am trying to apply a multi-select dropdown filter to a react-table component but, although the data is passing through and the selected values appear in the input select box, the table data isn't filtering as expected. In stead of filtering, the table data re-renders with new random data rows.

[image]

My codesandbox is https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-multi-select-filtering-forked-g5n9r

Any ideas where I am going wrong with the functionality?

Edit: it appears that filtered is calling an empty CustomFilter array each time:[image]

..rather than a single array with an id and a dynamic value array:

[image]