# React Multi select- how to filter through table columns

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter

[React-table multi select filter not filtering data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67333516/react-table-multi-select-filter-not-filtering-data/73039909?noredirect=1#comment129002282_73039909)

Hi there, just wondering if anyone has a solution for this? I am struggling with the same issue.

I have a multi select dropdown which needs to show any changes in a react table.

so these are my columns:  `{ Header: 'First Name', accessor: 'first_name', Cell: ({ cell }) => <ColorCell cell={cell} name="first_name" />, }, { Header: 'Last Name', accessor: 'last_name', Cell: ({ cell }) => <ColorCell cell={cell} name="last_name" />, },`

an example of my dropdown:

`//create a state to store the value const [valueState, setValueState] = useState('');  //handler function const handleSelectChange = (value) => {   setValueState(value); }  // on your onChange prop <SelectBox        value={valueState}        defaultValue=""        placeholder="Select columns"        isMulti        options={filterOptions}        onChange={ (value) => handleSelectChange (value) }        name="ColumnSelect"        label=""        isClearable />`

this is how I check for changes in the api:

`{_.includes(cell.row.values.has_changed, name) ? ( <p style={{ backgroundColor: ${getCellColor(name)} }}>{cell.value}</p> ) : ( <p style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>{cell.value}</p> )}`

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducable piece of code please?

Comment: can you edit your question with all the additions?

Comment: you can get help from here on how to ask; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask